# Inconsistent Execution in Bootloader-Only vs. Bootloader and Firmware Scenario

Tags: c, debugging, embedded, bootloader, firmware

I'm working with an embedded system where I have two separate ELF files: bootloader.elf and firmware.elf. I've set up my debugger to first flash bootloader.elf and then firmware.elf. When this sequence is followed, the system successfully executes the JumpToApplication function inside the bootloader, which then jumps to an entry point in the firmware. Here's the JumpToApplication function:

```c
void JumpToAdresse(uint32_t StackPointerAdresse,  uint32_t ProgramCounterAdresse)
{
    __asm volatile("msr msp, r0");
    __asm volatile ("ISB"); 
    __asm volatile("msr psp, r0");
    S32_SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)FIRMWARE_A_VECTOR_TABLE_ADRESSE;
    __asm volatile("mov pc, r1");
}
```

Called inside main of bootloader

```
    #define FIRMWARE_A_VECTOR_TABLE_ADRESSE     0x00002000
    uint32_t StackPointerAdress = *((volatile uint32_t*)FIRMWARE_A_VECTOR_TABLE_ADRESSE);
    uint32_t ProgramCounterAdress = *((volatile uint32_t*)(FIRMWARE_A_VECTOR_TABLE_ADRESSE + 4));
    JumpToAdresse(StackPointerAdress, ProgramCounterAdress);
```

This function is supposed to jump to the address 0x5021, and it does so correctly when both ELF files are flashed in sequence (using Debug Configuration 1,see below). However, if I only run bootloader.elf, configured to preserve the P-Flash area where my firmware resides (See Bootloader Configuration below), the jump doesn't execute correctly. Instead of jumping to the intended address, it goes to a seemingly random sequence of instructions:

```
00019d2c: push {r7}
00019d2e: add r7, sp, #0
00019d30: bkpt 0x0000
```

What could be causing this discrepancy in the execution sequence when only the bootloader is run, as opposed to when both the bootloader and firmware are flashed? Any insights into why the jump is not reaching the intended address in the single bootloader.elf scenario would be greatly appreciated.

### Debug Configuration and Informations

MCU: S32K146 Arm Cortex-M4

Debug Probe used: PEmicro Multilink Universal

#### DebugConfiguration Flashing Both Bootloader and Firmware

[image: DebugConfiguration Flashing Both Bootloader and Firmware]

#### DebugConfiguration Flashing Bootloader only and Preserving Firmware

[image: Bootloader only Config]

#### Sequence of Events

[image: Sequence]

EDIT 1: To clarify, in both scenarios (when flashing both bootloader.elf and firmware.elf, and when running only bootloader.elf), the Program Counter and Stack Pointer values are correct and consistent. Additionally, I have verified that the Flash Memory is properly preserved, and it contains the correct firmware. The issue specifically arises with the entry() jump, which fails in the bootloader-only execution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say only bootloader runs? Which parts of memory are programmed and what is the sequence of events?

Comment: Is this function supposed to also set up/reset the stack? You can't use local variables/parameters in C inside a function manually changing the stack pointer - your program would go bananas. The correct solution in that case is to write everything in assembler.

Comment: @user694733 I have two debug configurations one is Bootloader only (where only the bootloader.elf is flashed and run) and the other is bootloader.elf + kr_bis.elf (that is my firmware) that is flashed. When I run the configuration that flashes both everything works as intenden but when I run only the bootloader it doesnt.

Comment: @Lundin The JumpToApplication function works as intendend. But I also have a solution using __asm volatile("msr msp, r0");
 __asm volatile ("ISB"); 
 __asm volatile("msr psp, r0"); S32_SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)FIRMWARE_A_VECTOR_TABLE_ADRESSE; __asm volatile("mov pc, r1");

Comment: I added the sequence of Events @user694733

Comment: So where are your local variables stored? You crossed your fingers and hoped that the compiler would store them all in registers? Doesn't seem wise. Make them all `static` to see if that was the problem.

Comment: @Lundin I changed the function to my original function which used assembly commands and uses the function parameters which are defined behaviour to be saved from r0-r3 according to ARM Architecture Procedure Call Standard (AAPCS). But as I said I dont think the function itself is the problem since it works when using the DebugConfiguration Bootloader+Firmware

Comment: So in the modifier version, you don't actually call the function but just brute force the program counter? Where is `FIRMWARE_A_VECTOR_TABLE_ADRESSE` coming from? Is it an absolute address?

Comment: Ofcourse, I call the function from within my bootloader main() using the stackPointerAdresse and ProgramCounter Adresse saved inside the InterruptTable. See the EDITED Post

Comment: Okay so it starts to sound like a flashing issue of address 0x2000 perhaps? Does the content at 0x2000 - 0x20004 look ok in the debugger?

Comment: @Lundin Yes the content is correct running both debug configurations. The PC and SP Adress stays the same/is consistent. I start to think the Preserve Memory Range feature of Kinetis changes the Memory Protection and doesnt allow me to execute the code from there, that might be the problem.

Comment: Strictly it will jump to 0x5020.  The LSB is a Thumb mode indicator, not an address bit.

Comment: The SP and PC are read from the firmware image.  If there is no firmware image why would you expect any particular behaviour. What is at that address if there is no firmware?  If it it blank flash memory, I'd expect 0xFFFFFFFF, if it is RAM, it could be anything.

Another issue is that you need to be sure that interrupts are disabled and any pending interrupts cleared before switching the vector table to the firmware address.

Comment: @Clifford they are not they are read from 0x2000 which is the Interrupt Table and the first two entrys of this Tables represent the SP&PC (I confirmed with debugger). The second part with Interrupts is missing, thats correct.

Comment: I am aware if that, but the vector table is (normally) part of the application firmware which you say is not present.